# How to force active focus/select QML Tab under QML TabView?

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I have a `TabView` with 3 `Tab`s and I want to change the focus/select the third `Tab` when a button is pressed. I've tried `forceActiveFocus`, but it does not work.

```
//.qml
TabView {
    Tab {
        id: redTab
        title: "Red"
        Rectangle { color: "red" }
    }
    Tab {
        id: blueTab
        title: "Blue"
        Rectangle { color: "blue" }
    }
    Tab {
        id: greenTab
        title: "Green"
        Rectangle { color: "green" }
    }
}

ToolButton {
    inconSource: "lock.png"
    onClicked: {
        greenTab.forceActiveFocus() // does not work?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`currentIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tabview.html#currentIndex-prop):

```
TabView {
    id: tabView
    //...
}
//...
tabView.currentIndex = 2
```